# Перевод ASCII кода в String C++

Tags: c++, строки, ascii

На вход даётся строка, из которой я достаю символы. После преобразования символов в строку, я получаю её ASCII код. Необходимо данный код перевести в символы и на выходе получить `string`.

Пример кода:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string get_middle(string input){
int i = input.length();
if (i % 2 == 0) return to_string(input[i / 2 - 1]) + to_string(input[i / 2]);
if (i == 1) return input;
else return to_string(input[i / 2]);
}
```

Тестовое значение: `string input = "testing"`.

На выходе необходимо получить `"t"`.

Программа выводит `116` (ASCII код символа t).

Comment: Совершенно непонятно, что вы хотите получить... то, что вы делаете, выглядит по меньшей мере странно. Вам надо получить средний символ строки?

Comment: Здесь Вам зачем два символа? return to_string(input[i / 2 - 1]) + to_string(input[i / 2]);

Comment: @Harry  необходимо получить средний символ строки. Если строка имеет чётное кол-во символов - это будет два символа. Если нечетное - один символ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот то

> необходимо получить средний символ строки. Если строка имеет чётное кол-во символов - это будет два символа. Если нечетное - один символ

чего вы так сложно добиваетесь:

```
string middle(const string& s)
{
    return s.substr((s.size()-1)/2,2-s.size()%2);
}
```

Понятно, что в строке должен присутствовать хотя бы один символ...